# Add additional text to combobox after retrieving from database

Tags: c++, database, qt, combobox, qt-creator

How would I add a "key" to each of the combo box options? So if the code below gave me a combobox with:

apple

lemon

cherry

banana

mango

```
QSqlQuery query;
QStringList Columns;
query.prepare(" SELECT * "
              " FROM \"incdt_systemType\" ");
query.exec();
query.first();
_SQLQuerymodel->setQuery(query);
ui->_version->setModel(_SQLQuerymodel);
ui->_version->setModelColumn(_SQLQuerymodel->record().indexOf("incdt_systemtype_code"));
```

How would I add 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., in front of it?

So that the end result would be a combo box showing:

1. apple
2. leon
3. cherry
4. banana
5. mango

Comment: Which is the moment you read the input at the begining? In which of the lines of the code?

Comment: query.prepare is where i get all of my valid inputs that I will be putting into my combo box. SetModelColumn is where it actually gets placed.

Comment: Can you put a link to a definition/description of QSqlQuery? Do you use at all that variable Columns?

Comment: QSqlQuery is basically what you use to send commands to the database. in query.prepare(" SELECT * FROM \"incdt_systemType\" "); I'm taking everything (the *) from the database table named incdt_systemType.

Comment: Where are apple, leon, cherry etc. stored, in which data structure? If you are able to tell this, than it is easy to add the number in front

Comment: it is stored in the database table, which I cannot edit. I need to add 1. independently.

Comment: You read it from the database table, but then while in use it is stored somewhere where you can probably edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do that through the query already. I can only provide the Oracle SQL Syntax, but other DBMSs might have similar options:

Assuming you have a table "fruits" with a column "name", then a query like

```
SELECT rownum || '. ' || name FROM fruits
```

would do the trick.

Another option is to subclass `QSqlQueryModel` and overload the [data()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/qsqlquerymodel.html#data) method somewhat like this:

```
QVariant MyOwnSQLQueryModel::data(const QModelIndex & item, int role ) const
{
    if( role == Qt::DisplayRole && item.column() == _nameColumnIndex )
    {
        return QString( "%1. %2" )
               .arg( item.row() )
               .arg( QSqlQueryModel::data( item, role ) );
    }
    // else: default behaviour
    return QSqlQueryModel::data( item, role );
}
```